# Array to string conversion in Error

Tags: php, arrays

```
$keyNames = array();
$keyVals = array();

foreach ($varArray as $key => $name) { 

    $keyNames .= $key . ', ';
}

foreach ($varArray as $key => $val) { 

    $keyVals .= '\'' . $val. '\', ';
}

// build query
$sql = "INSERT INTO Organizations (";
$sql .= rtrim($keyNames, ", ");
$sql .= ") VALUES (";
$sql .= rtrim($keyVals, ", ");
$sql .= ");";
echo "<div style=\"padding:5px;background-color:#efefef\">".$sql."</div>"; // this output is working
```

I am trying to get the above code to work without error. IT currently works but I am getting  " Array to string conversion in" error even though I am getting the result that I am expecting.

I am trying to build an sql query from array elements. Both loops throw an error but the echo SQL is giving me what I want. I just want to get rid of the error. I have tried (string) and (array) and implode() and join() but I have not been able to clear the error.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from trying to concatenate a string onto an array. Because you are using `$keyNames` and `$keyValues` strictly as strings, there is no need to initialize them as arrays - simply use strings and the error will go away.

Change

```
$keyNames = array(); 
$keyVals = array();
```

to

```
$keyNames = $keyVals = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure seems quite useles because there is [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) function for merging array's elements:

```
$keyNames  = implode(',', array_keys($varArray));
$keyValues = '"' . implode('","', $varArray) . '"';
```

And SQL:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Organizations (' . $keyNames . ') VALUES (' . $keyValues . ')';
```

Comment: You're not putting quotes around the values.

Comment: I added the code from above and got the same error Notice: Array to string conversion in $keyNames = implode(', ', array_keys($varArray));
$keyVals = implode(', ', array_map(function($val) {
    return "'$val'";
}, array_values($varArray)));

Comment: Ok I found out what the issue was... one of my form elements a multi select was actually an array so after imploding that into a string the form worked fine with no errors

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you're initializing the variables as arrays, and then concatenating strings to them. What you want is:

```
$keyNames = implode(', ', array_keys($varArray));
$keyVals = implode(', ', array_map(function($val) {
    return "'$val'";
}, array_values($varArray)));
```